# How to redirect on conditions with class based views in Django 1.3?

Tags: django, redirect, django-class-based-views

I am using a ListView that list videos according to tags. The filtering happens in get_queryset(). I'd like to redirect the user to another page if the tag doesn't contains any video.

With a function, it would be easy. Query, check the queryset, redirect. With a class, I fail doing so:

```
class VideosView(generic.ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
            This work.
        """

        tag = self.kwargs.get('tag', None)

        self.videos = Video.on_site.all()

        if tag:
            self.videos = Video.tagged.with_all(tag, self.videos)

        return self.videos

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This doesn't work because self.videos doesn't exist yet.
        """
        if not self.videos:
            return redirect('other_page')

        return super(Videos, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it:

```
def render_to_response(self, context):

    if not self.videos:
        return redirect('other_page')

    return super(VideosView, self).render_to_response(context)
```

This is called for all HTTP methods

Comment: I agree with the solution but, don't you think that the view's dispatch method is more appropriate ?

Comment: Well, dispatch will call the get or post methods which call query set which get the videos list, so it doesn't fell so natural to me. Why do you think it would be better ?

Comment: Here are the django 1.3 docs on [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: The answer would benefit for a little more context. I'm guessing there's a basic get_queryset function and no get/post HTTP Method handler get_query_set function. You wouldn't typically want to do a whole lot of 'work' and then just make a redirect at the very end of the request. If the need to redirect could be determined before/without accessing the queryset then the Dispatch method would be a better place.

Answer (score 40):

I know this is old, but I actually agree with Tommaso.  The dispatch() method is what handles the request and returns the HTTP response.  If you want to adjust the response of the view, thats the place to do it. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) on dispatch().

```
class VideosView(ListView):
    # use model manager
    queryset = Videos.on_site.all()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if there is some video onsite
        if not queryset:
            return redirect('other_page')
        else:
            return super(VideosView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # other method overrides here
```

Comment: If queryset is dynamic, how do you get it ?

Comment: You should still have a queryset object available to you. Do you have an example?

Comment: If i remember well, ListView generate dynamic queryset in get_queryset, and then pagination in get_context. Using dispatch seems to call them, this is uncool if you want to redirect according to that.

Comment: How is it "uncool?" Dispatch is where the request is handled and the response returned. It would seem to me that if you wanted to deal with redirect conditionals, that would be the very place you would want them.

Comment: How do you access the queryset to check the condition if it's called in dispatch ?

Comment: You can access the method by calling `self.get_queryset()` then run a conditional on that.

Comment: First, it will be called a second time by dispatch(), second, you wont get the paginated version.

Comment: The question was regarding where to put redirect logic. You're right, the paginated logic wont get called, but if you're redirecting, then you won't need a paginated version of your queryset.

Comment: But you need the pagination logic to redirect based on the queryset. How do you know the content of the current paginated queryset ? In you case you would only have the entire queryset. It's not the same at all.

Comment: @e-satis I had the exact same issue, `render_to_response` could not be a better place for that. Theoretically, `dispatch` handles the redirects but when all calculations have to be made before redirecting, `render_to_response` is the place.

Answer (score -4):

According to django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView) :

in url.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     ...
    url(r'^go-to-django/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://djangoproject.com'), name='go-to-django'),
..
)
```

Comment: It forget completly about the condition part in the OP.