# Django: "How to get the slug from url() before passing it to MyClass.as_view()?" or "How to check if registration is open?"

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I want to check if a user is allowed to register for a specific event. I thought in order to save code I could do it like the `login_required` decorator right between the `url()` and `MyClass.as_view()`. But how do I get that slug? Or is this solution totally wrong? (I unfortunatelly can't use the `user_passes_test` because I don't want to test someting on the user but on the url.)

So I tryed this:

views.py

```
from registration.models import Event
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def reg_is_open(event_slug):
    """
    Return True if registration is open.
    """
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=event_slug)
    if event.open_date <= timezone.now() and event.cut_off >= timezone.now():
        return True

def allow_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    """
    Check weather registration is open and user is logged in.
    Returns to registration start page if registration is closed.
    """
    slug = initkwargs.get('event') # Does not work!
    if not reg_is_open(slug):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registration:event_index', args=slug))
    return login_required(cls.as_view(**initkwargs))
    # Also works when I remove **initkwargs. That means that what I'm looking for just passes...
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from registration import views

event_patterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^person/$', views.allow_view(views.PersonList), name='person_list'), 
    # instead of 
    # url(r'^person/$', login_required(views.PersonList.as_view()), name='person_list'),
    # ...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<event>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$', views.EventDetails.as_view(), name='event_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<event>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/', include(event_patterns)),
    # ...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5433410/1566605

Comment: Where is the slug supposed to be coming from? You have that parameter in your `event_index` URL pattern but not in your decorated `person_list` pattern.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry The captured slug `event` is passed. [See here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your view is a `DetailView` of the event, correct? In that case, use something along the lines of:

```
class EventDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Event

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user not in self.object.registered_users.all():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            return super(EventDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This assumes that you have a M2M key between `User` and `Event` models, called `registered_users` on the `Event` side; change the code to fit your situation.

Comment: Yes I'm using the `DetailView` here. Your suggestion is similar to what I coded now but a bit more complex for I wanted to have a cascade of redirects and my hope was that I don't have to write it in every generic class view. I was looking if I could do something with subclassing but I didn't find a solution (for I also use other generics like `ListView`, `CreateView`, `UpdateView`).

Comment: Maybe you could write a mixin which takes care of what you need?